# Is there a standard way to know whether window is floating or tiled?

Tags: linux, window-managers, ewmh, icccm

I'm modifying taskbar to show only floating or minimized windows. I know that there are **ICCCM** and **EWMH** standards. Can I use them to check whether window is floating or tiled? Or is there something else that I can use?

I don't want to do it specifically for window manager, because I'm about to switch to another.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, floating / tiled is nothing that EWMH or ICCCM defines.